# Manipulate Data, based on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

My data is like this:

```
Unique_Number       information       complete_information 
    1                 Hello              Hello World 
    1                 Hello                 
    1                 Wrong Info      
    2                 R                  R, Python 
    2                
    3                 OverFlow           Stackoverflow 
    4                 Only info
```

The thing that I want to achieve:

**If a Unique_number is the same (e.g.: all the 1's, all the 2's etc.), it should take the values of the complete_information column, and paste it into the information column.**

Desired output:

```
Unique_Number       information       complete_information 
    1                 Hello World          Hello World 
    1                 Hello World                
    1                 Hello World      
    2                 R, Python            R, Python 
    2                 R, Python
    3                 Stackoverflow        Stackoverflow 
    4                 Only info
```

I couldn't figure out a good logic for this. I tried to loop over all the Unique_Numbers, and paste the complete_information values, if an Unique_Numbers was the same.. but ran into a messy dataset.

Comment: why  3 is stackoverflow, not overFlow ..? 'If a Unique_number is the same' what does this mean? same as ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
df.information=np.where(df.complete_information.notna(),df.complete_information,
                                                           df.information)
df.information=df.groupby('Unique_Number')['information'].transform('first')
print(df)
```

---

```
   Unique_Number    information complete_information
0              1    Hello World          Hello World
1              1    Hello World                 None
2              1    Hello World                 None
3              2      R, Python            R, Python
4              2      R, Python                 None
5              3  Stackoverflow        Stackoverflow
6              4      Only info                 None
```

(*if the cells are blank strings in `complete_information` , this may require them to be replaced by `np.nan`) , or replace `df.complete_information.notna()` in `np.where(..)` with `df.complete_information.ne('')`*

Answer (score 1):

With *mask* based ob *shifted* values ([pandas.Series.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)):

```
In [723]: m = (df['Unique_Number'].shift(-1) == df['Unique_Number']) | (df['Unique_Number'] == df['Unique_Number'].shift(1))

In [724]: df.loc[m, 'information'] = df.loc[m, 'complete_information'].fillna(method='ffill')

In [725]: df
Out[725]: 
   Unique_Number  information complete_information
0              1  Hello World          Hello World
1              1  Hello World                 None
2              1  Hello World                 None
3              2    R, Python            R, Python
4              2    R, Python                 None
5              3     OverFlow        Stackoverflow
6              4    Only info                 None
```